# zeepを使ってwsdlにアクセスするとssl.SSLCertVerificationError:となってしまう。

Tags: python

初心者です。
アプリケーションの設定変更をSOAPで行う必要があり、pythonを利用してコーディング中です。
早速以下コードでクライアントのオブジェクトを作成しようとしたのですが、失敗してしまいました。
対応方法などもしございましたらご教示いただけると助かります。

```
from zeep import Client
from zeep import xsd

client = Client("https://192.168.xxx.xxxx/sms/test.php?wsdl") 
client_admin = client.bind("test","5022")
```

エラーコード

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='192.168.xxx.xxxx', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /sms/test.php?wsdl 
(Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:1108)')))
```

Comment: `client = Client("https://～`行の下に`client.transport.session.verify = False`を追加して、[SSL証明書を無視](https://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/transport.html#tls-verification)させる、または`"https://`を`"http://`に変更するいずれかの対応で動くでしょうか？

Comment: ご教示頂きありがとうございました。SSL証明書を無視させても同じエラーメッセージが表示されました。また、システム上httpアクセスに変更することが出来ませんでした。どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 一旦同じプログラム内にwsdlファイルを置いて、利用できるか試してみようかと思います。色々とご教示ありがとうございました。
client = Client("test.wsdl") 
client_admin = client.bind("test","5022")